# How do I send keys to an active window in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, scripting

I want my script to open an application and send keys to it after it's opened. Currently, if I run the script, it opens the app but does not send the keys.

If I run just the send keys after the app has already been opened, it works.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware Horizon View Client\vmware-view.exe" -Wait -WindowStyle Normal

$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('VMware')
Sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('~')
Sleep 3
$wshell.SendKeys('username')
Sleep 2
$wshell.SendKeys('{TAB}')
Sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('password')
```

Comment: maybe you are not waiting for the app to open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `-Wait` with `Start-Process`, you're *blocking* the call until the launched process *terminates*.

Thus, your attempts to send keystrokes will invariably fail, because they'll be sent *after the target program has terminated*.

---

Therefore:

- Don't use `-Wait`
- Use `-PassThru`, which makes [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) emit a process-information object representing the newly launched process, whose `.ID` property contains the PID (process ID).
- For more reliable targeting, you can pass a PID to `$wshell.AppActivate()`
- The general caveat applies: sending keystrokes, i.e. *simulating user input* is inherently unreliable.

```
$ps = Start-Process -PassThru -FilePath "C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware Horizon View Client\vmware-view.exe" -WindowStyle Normal

$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell

# Wait until activating the target process succeeds.
# Note: You may want to implement a timeout here.
while (-not $wshell.AppActivate($ps.Id)) {
  Start-Sleep -MilliSeconds 200
}

$wshell.SendKeys('~')
Sleep 3
$wshell.SendKeys('username')
Sleep 2
$wshell.SendKeys('{TAB}')
Sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('password')
```